# How to use ng-if?

Tags: angularjs

I have this value:

```
vm.Data
```

I need to check if the value above not null using **ng-if**.

If value is not null I want to display data if null I want to display "Empty":

```
<span ng-if="vm.Data != null">{{vm.Data}}</span>
<span ng-if="vm.Data == null">Empty</span>
```

Are the two rows above correct? Or I can implement it another way?

Comment: this code will work and it is the only way to use `ng-if`

Comment: Why not add a property to `vm` like `dataDisplay` that yields "Empty" if `Data` is null?

Comment: You can also simply do `<span>{{vm.Data || 'Empty'}}</span>`. But yes, what you suggest works. What haven't you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for !vm.Data:

```
<span ng-if="!vm.Data">Empty</span>
```

Comment: what if `vm.Data == 0`?